# Why does npm update fail?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having trouble updating npm.

I want to get back to a Laravel project that I put aside a few months back and realized that several components of my project would need updating so I started with that. I successfully updated Visual Studio Code to version 1.82.2, then tried to update npm with:

```
npm update -g
```

Instead of a nice clean update, I got all of this:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'npm@10.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.14.2', npm: '9.1.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been 
merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to 
the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-datasource@3.3.2: The `apollo-datasource` package is part of Apollo Server 
v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-errors@3.3.1: The `apollo-server-errors` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-plugin-base@3.7.2: The `apollo-server-plugin-base` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-types@3.8.0: The `apollo-server-types` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-express@3.12.1: The `apollo-server-express` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated shortid@2.2.16: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-reporting-protobuf@3.4.0: The `apollo-reporting-protobuf` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 20 package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.   
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-env@4.2.1: The `apollo-server-env` package is part of Apollo Server 
v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/utils.fetcher` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.11.0: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no 
longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-core@3.12.1: The `apollo-server-core` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.

added 236 packages, removed 111 packages, and changed 1096 packages in 14m

168 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
npm notice
npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.1.2 -> 10.1.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.1.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.1.0 to update!
npm notice
```

I took the notice at the end to mean that I should use that command to do my npm update but got this:

```
PS C:\Laravel\voyago02> npm install -g npm@10.1.0
npm WARN cli npm v10.1.0 does not support Node.js v16.14.2. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.       
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.1.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.1.0
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"10.1.0","node":"v16.14.2"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Reinh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-17T21_41_20_490Z-debug-0.log
```

What is going on here and what do I need to do to get npm updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first.

1. Since you are using Node.js v16, you can continue using npm v9. No need to update that.

The message you see is just to let you know that there is an updated version available (if you are using a higher version of Node.js).

On a side note, I would recommend you to use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [NVS](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs) to manage different Node.js versions easily.

2. Many of the dependencies you are using are outdated. Those are the `WARN deprecated` messages you are seeing.

Your package will continue to work, but it's good to update.

3. The `WARN EBADENGINE` means that the Node.js version you have is not compatible with the minimum Node.js version required by some package.

You can try to solve this by:

- Upgrading to Node.js `v18`. You can use NVM or NVS for this
- Try installing a version of this package that supports Node.js `v16`

4. Check the packages that can be updated easily.

```
npx npm-check-updates
```

Refer https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates for more details.

Comment: NVM is a bad idea in this context, as it doesn't support Windows. https://github.com/jasongin/nvs is better for the case, never had a problem with it for years

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update NPM, you'll have to update **Node** as well. That's what it said.

If you still want to update, go to https://nodejs.org/en/download/current and get the new installer (you may choose v20, as it's entering LTS in October)

There is a chance your package won't build or run after update, that'd mean it's not compatible with the latest Node and you have to install an older one.

If you want to install multiple versions of Node at once, to both have the latest features and being able to work with old stuff, you may use https://github.com/jasongin/nvs
You'll need to `nvs add 20` to install node@20, `nvs link 20` to set is as default, and `nvs use 16` to use node@16 in the current shell. See docs for more info.